# asp.net, razor: when model is returned it will construct it anew

Tags: asp.net, razor

i am inflating my view like this

```
public ActionResult Tagging(int id, ItemType itemType, bool autoCloseWindow = false, bool refreshOpener = false)
        {
            var model = new TaggingViewModel(id, itemType);

            return View("Tagging", model);
        }
```

I give the params id and itemtype to retrieve the correct data.

I display the data (correclty) like so:

```
<td>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].IsChecked, new { @class = "langCheck" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].ItemId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].GlobalTaggingId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainNodes[i].children[y].ItemType)
</td>
```

But if I press save in my form field the model is returned empty:

[image]

I found out that the reason is that in the params of the saveTagging method I instiate the model anew, but with out the params (as you cannot pass them here) and therefore get an empty model returned.

but:

1.) How do I give it params?

2.) Even if I were to give the params say statically, I dont want the old model returned, I want the altered model from the front end returned.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was doing ALMOST everything right.

You CANNOT simply return the whole model with an ID, but you can simply return the property from the model that you need. Meaning I changed the params in my Action Result from:

```
public ActionResult SaveTagging(TaggingViewModel taggedModel, bool autoCloseWindow = false)
```

to:

```
public ActionResult SaveTagging(List<NodeModelWithCheckBoxes> MainNodes, bool autoCloseWindow = false)
```

With

```
List<NodeModelWithCheckBoxes> MainNodes
```

being the list with the values that were returned null. This list ofc is part of my model `taggedModel`
This way, it isnt instantiated anew and all my values are getting passed into this object.